# A solid intro/tutorial to programming (for a SmartDevice with Windows CE & Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I'm a beginning programmer who needs to write a simple program in C# for use on a Windows CE 5.0 device. Specifically, I'm working with Visual Studio 2008 and an SDK for Psion Teklogix devices. I've not been able to find a relevant introduction or tutorial for this sort of programming, and as I'm not familiar with C# or any of its relatives (and don't have any knowledgeable programmers around me), I can't seem to get off the ground. I've perused the following tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb330928.aspx
But the code given for C# here doesn't function with the References I've got, as a consequence of my SDK. So, my question is - are there specific tutorials, blogs, books, etc that may help me here? Or do I need to learn C# by doing the tutorials for console applications and then switch to working with the SDK-relevant resources once I'm mildly competent? Thanks in advance for any answers/advice.

Answer (score 2):

The Compact Framework is largely a subset of what you have on the desktop.  When you add a device to the mix, you're going to have challenges around deployment and debugging, and I think trying to get through those while also trying to learn the language is simply setting an unreasonably high barrier for yourself.

Start out with a basic "intro to C#" book or set of tutorials and just work on the desktop for now.  Most of the fundamentals are going to directly translate to the device when you get there.

Spend time on the desktop  doing a bit of what you need - build up some of the business objects you're going to need and even mock up some abstracted UI.

Once you are comfortable with the language and the tools, *then* go into some of the device-specific tutorials so the only thing you're trying to learn at that point is how to deploy and debug with CoreCon.